# C#, How can I read/write commands to a Linux SBC(BeagleBone) through a serial port in a certain order?

Tags: c#, wpf, console, serial-port, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to write a command to a BeagleBone over serial port and then read that output but for some reasons it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            port.ReadTimeout = 500;
            port.WriteTimeout = 500;


            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            port.Open();

            port.WriteLine("debian\r\n"); //default login username
            port.WriteLine("temppwd\r\n");//default login password


            void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {

                    string message = port.ReadExisting();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);


            }
```

For example, `port.WriteLine("debian\r\n")` seems to correctly work but right after that `port.WriteLine("temppwd\r\n")` doesn't seem to work. I am expecting to see`debian@beaglebone:~$:` printed out in the debug console but after `port.WriteLine("debian\r\n")` all that is printed out is blank space. Is this because I need to wait for the first command to execute before the second? To my knowledge I thought the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` took care of that. Thanks, any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, I am able to establish a connection to the SBC because in the debug console the default text at login is printed out.

Comment: For example, are you able to communicate with other terminal programs? [Serial Terminal](https://learn.adafruit.com/windows-tools-for-the-electrical-engineer/serial-terminal) Or refer to these programs. [Termie: A Simple RS232 Terminal](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23656/Termie-A-Simple-RS232-Terminal), [GUI based Serial Communication Program using C#](https://www.xanthium.in/building-opensource-gui-based-serial-port-communication-program-dot-net-framework-and-arduino), [C# Serial Communication Terminal](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cserialcomterm/)

Comment: @kunif I'm able to communicate with the with the SBC because in the debug output console it prints out the default text at the beginning of login. Its after I enter the username that things don't work.

Comment: Is it necessary to set all the port setting conditions of the debug console I/O to the same in your program and send the password after the prompt for the password is displayed? It seems bad to send the password before the system prompts you. For Example. [How to Connect the BeagleBone Black via Serial over USB](https://www.dummies.com/computers/beaglebone/how-to-connect-the-beaglebone-black-via-serial-over-usb/)

Comment: @kunif Yeah I think that's the problem. I don't know how I can can send the password once the system prompts me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple sleep between commands works just fine, and might suffice for your use case:

```
    port.WriteLine("debian\r\n"); 
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    port.WriteLine("temppwd\r\n"); 
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    port.WriteLine("ls /\r\n");
```

A better solution would be parsing the received data. Note, the "message" string that you are getting from the serial port event

- might not contain the whole line
- might contain multiple lines
- might never end with a CR/LF (if its a prompt)
- might contain terminal control characters